# When did Daredevil's weapon first appear with a rope attached?

Tags: story-identification, marvel, daredevil

I'm trying to find out what the first issue of Daredevil where his batons / eskrima had a rope attached between them more like a manrikigusari?

I found someone online mentioned Issue 252 says he created his weapons himself, though I haven't got the issue to verify that. The [Marvel Wikia](http://marvel.wikia.com/Daredevil%27s_Billy_Club) states

> Daredevil's Billy Club has been lost or destroyed on more than one occasion:
>
> - Daredevil #80 lost in New York Harbor and never found.
> - Daredevil #116 destroyed battling Death Stalker
> - Daredevil #122 broken battling Blackwing.
> - Daredevil (Vol. 3) #6 broken fighting Bruiser
> - Daredevil (Vol. 3) #25 broken fighting Ikari
>
> Daredevil's Billy Club has changed constantly in design throughout the years including being colored in both red and white colors.

Does anyone know what the first appearance of his weapon with rope is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first issue to depict Daredevil's baton with a rope was *Daredevil* (vol 1) #7 (cover date April 1965). At that time, however, the rope did not attach the two batons together and instead functioned more as a grapple.

The first time that Daredevil's two batons were *connected* by a rope was on the cover of *Daredevil* (vol 1) #369 (insignia November 1997), but in that story, the batons still functioned as two separate weapons. It wasn't until issue 372 (insignia February 1998) that the weapon was depicted as similar to a manrikigusari on-panel. This became standard with *Daredevil* (vol 2) #1 (insignia November 1998).

Except for occasional appearances of the old, separate batons when drawn by Michael Lark, the connected batons, or manrikigusari, remained Daredevil's standard weapons until *Daredevil* (vol 3) #1 (insignia September 2011), when artist Paulo Rivera redesigned it as a three-part weapon, with one free baton and two connected ones.

Answer (score 8):

Daredevil #7. Prior to that the Billyclub had a hinge, but this is the first issue where its ever depicted as containing a cable. In fact, Daredevil makes a point of describing how he just barely installed and is eager to try it out as a grappling hook.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. In this issue, The rope is built into the hilt and functions like a grapple, not a rope between pieces that can function like a nun-chuck.

Comment: There is no "rope" between the sections, unless it has changed very, very recently, it is the same cable that is used for the Billy Club. Once the cable was introduced, Daredevil started to split his billyclub in half, at first we would use one section as transportation and then throw the loose section. However, that eventually evolved into him shooting the top section of the billyclub off at enemies while it was attached via cable to the section he was holding, which in turn led to the nunchaku setup. The question was when the "rope" 1st appeared, and the answer is that it 1st appears in #7.

Comment: The OP seems happy with this, so who am I to argue.